# Parameter box appearing when running SQL statement in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have the following update query that works in design mode of Access. I have inserted it into a VBA procedure and want to update the recordset with the windows ID of the user by declaring this as a variable  -

```
    UserName = Environ$("Username")

    UpdateSQL = "UPDATE ChecklistResults SET ManagerID = " & UserName & " " _
    & "WHERE (((ChecklistResults.ClientID)=Forms!TeamLeader!ComClientNotFin)" _
    & "And ((ChecklistResults.DateofChecklist)=Forms!TeamLeader!ComDateSelect)" _
    & "And ((ChecklistResults.ManagerID) Is Null));"

DoCmd.RunSQL UpdateSQL
```

My problem is when I click the command button to run the procedure a message box appears with my Windows ID as the title and it asks to 'Enter a Parameter Value' instead of inserting it directly to the table. I am not sure but it seems the SQL statement is incorrect as the windows ID is not being picked up as a variable

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes around the user name value so the db engine will interpret it as a literal text string instead of a parameter name.

That change should resolve your immediate issue.  Beyond that, include spaces before `WHERE` and `AND`.  Also execute the query with DAO's `Execute` method and include the *dbFailOnError* option.

```vb
UpdateSQL = "UPDATE ChecklistResults SET ManagerID = '" & UserName & "'" _
    & " WHERE ClientID=Forms!TeamLeader!ComClientNotFin" _
    & " And DateofChecklist=Forms!TeamLeader!ComDateSelect" _
    & " And ManagerID Is Null;"
Debug.Print UpdateSQL
'DoCmd.RunSQL UpdateSQL
CurrentDb.Execute UpdateSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp it seems to be picking up the Windows ID as it is printing in the Immediate window but I am getting a runtime error 3061 now. "Too few parameters. expected 2"

Comment: Copy the completed statement from the Immediate window and paste it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer.  When you run it from there, what are the names of the parameters?

Comment: Each of the parameters are preceded by ChecklistResults. (the name of the table). I have copied this into VBA and am still getting the same error message. when I run it the docmd.runsql route it works